# How can I set and preserve an environment variable?

Tags: android, environment-variables

I want a variable that every process on the system can read. I don't know whether an environment variable is the right thing for this in Android, but 
in Linux, I can set an environment variable with

```
VARIABLE=value
export VARIABLE
```

I can make it persistent by appending these two lines to the file .bashrc (or whatever the file is called, depending on the shell). Then after a restart, every process can read the variable.

How can I do the same thing on the Android system?

Comment: For what would you want to do such thing in Android?

Comment: Analyse the behaviour of different apps running at the same time. By setting LD_PRELOAD I can modify the relevant C methods to log into a file whose path would be a second global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set environment variables in android what you can do is use shared preference which can be accessed through out your app later